# SSIS loading .csv flat files using For Each Loop Container : Execute SQL Task expression to populate the audit table with Row Count

Tags: ssis, rowcount, tracker, foreach-loop-container, audit-tables

I am loading many .csv files into a SQL Server table using SSIS (Visual Studio 2017).

I am using For Each Loop Container.  I have two user variables - FileName (string) and RowCnt (int)

I have developed an audit table (dbo.FEfiles) to track each file loaded along with the number of records in each file.

Audit table has two columns:

1) FileName(varchar(20)

2) RowCount(int)

After the setting up of the Data Flow Task inside the For Each Loop Container, I have an Execute SQL Task that connects to my audit table.

In this Execute SQL Task, in the Expression tab, under the SQLStatementSource, I have the following expression to get the file name alone:

"INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName)  SELECT  '" + @[User::Filename] + "' "

This parses correctly when I evaluate the expression, I get:

INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName)  SELECT  'filename.CSV'

Now, how do I add the variable for the RowCnt, which has integer data type ?

I tried many options such as the one below:

"INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName,RowCount)  SELECT  '" + @[User::Filename] + "', + (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] "

When I evaluate the expression, I get the following:

INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName,RowCount)  SELECT  'filename.CSV', **+ (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt]**

I need to instead get this: INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName,RowCount)  SELECT  'filename.CSV', **0**

Can you kindly help me in getting the right expression ?

I even watched this video, but not able to figure out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um7tDy9jZRs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl.

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.FEFiles (FileName,RowCount) VALUES ('" + @[User::Filename] + "'," +  (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] + ")"
```

Per users comments had to put RowCount into brackets for column name.

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.FEFiles (FileName,[RowCount]) VALUES ('" + @[User::Filename] + "'," + (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] + ")"
```

String parts

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.FEFiles (FileName,[RowCount]) VALUES ('" 
+ 
@[User::Filename] 
+ 
"'," 
+  
(DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] 
+ 
")"
```

Comment: Although the expression is evaluated correctly, I get the following error while running the SSIS package:

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName,RowCount) VALUES..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RowCount'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem when I mention column names with the name of the table, where insertions are to be made.  INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles (FileName,RowCount)

Comment: I am able to run the SSIS package successfully by removing the column names:

"INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles  SELECT  '" + @[User::Filename] + "' , " + (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt]
(or)

"INSERT INTO dbo.FEfiles  VALUES ('" + @[User::Filename] + "'," + (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] + ")"

Comment: But I would ideally need to mention the column names in the table, since I plan to add a few more columns into the dbo.FEfiles Audit-Tracker table.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Also is there any rule book for this sort of parsing in SSIS? Am not able to understand when to use a single quotation(') or a double quotation("). How to use a variable, etc.  I have just been taking the codes from the internet.  I am spending hours for this coding !

Comment: Figured out: RowCount is a keyword:  so need to add it in square bracket as [RowCount]. Answer:  "INSERT INTO dbo.FEFiles (FileName,[RowCount]) VALUES  ('" + @[User::Filename] + "'," + (DT_WSTR, 12) @[User::RowCnt] + ")"